# Feed subtasks with values, how to do?

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future

I want a main thread which can give values to a number of subtasks (where the subtasks takes long time to execute) and where I do not want to end the subtasks and restart them with new values.
I try to use promise and future, but going this route is going to be complicated, since the promise and futures is not "reusable" or in fact I can not do two future.get() in a row...

Here is a code example, but this is not executing since the two future.get() in the print_int-task will run directly after each other!

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <functional>     // std::ref
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <future>         // std::promise, std::future

void print_int(std::future<int>& input_future, std::promise<void>& done_promise)
{
    std::cout << "Print thread starts!" << std::endl;

    int x = input_future.get(); 
    while (x > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Recived value: " << x;
        done_promise.set_value();
        std::cout << " done is set" << std::endl;

        int x = input_future.get();
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main thread starts!" << std::endl;

    std::promise<int> input_prom;                     
    std::promise<void> done_promise;
    std::future<void> done_future = done_promise.get_future();
    std::future<int> input_fut = input_prom.get_future();    
    std::thread thred(print_int, std::ref(input_fut), std::ref(done_promise)); 

    int counter = 10;

    while (counter > 1)
    {

        input_prom.set_value(counter);                         // fulfill promise

        //the print_int thread excecutes and prints

        done_future.get(); // wait until its printed
        counter--;
    }

    // (synchronizes with getting the future)
    thred.join();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: using std::async instead of std::thread will at least simplify things a bit. Also learn a bit more about lambda expressions (so you don't need to use std::ref). Also note using references with threads can be a bit tricky (take care the referred objects outlive the lifetime of the thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a typical producer-consumer problem, you should send a new future for every task you need to execute, the "sending" should be done with a thread-safe queue, and the "returning" should be done using the promise as follows.

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <functional>     // std::ref
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <future>         // std::promise, std::future
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <optional>

class SPSCQueue
{
public:
    using OptionalPromisePair = std::optional<std::pair<int, std::promise<std::string>>>;
    void put(OptionalPromisePair&& p)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_mut);        
            m_queue.push(std::move(p));
        }
        m_cv.notify_one();
    }
    OptionalPromisePair get()
    {
        if (this->m_queue.size() == 0)
        {
            std::unique_lock lk(m_mut);
            m_cv.wait(lk, [this]{ return this->m_queue.size() != 0; });
        }
        std::scoped_lock lk2(m_mut);
        OptionalPromisePair ret = std::move(m_queue.front());
        m_queue.pop();
        return ret;
    }
private:
    std::queue<OptionalPromisePair> m_queue;
    std::mutex m_mut;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
};

void print_int(SPSCQueue& queue)
{
    std::cout << "Print thread starts!" << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {
        SPSCQueue::OptionalPromisePair p = queue.get();
        if (!p)
        {
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "Recived value: " << (*p).first;
        (*p).second.set_value("val");
        std::cout << " future is set" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main thread starts!" << std::endl;

    SPSCQueue queue;
    std::thread thred(print_int, std::ref(queue)); 

    int counter = 10;

    while (counter > 1)
    {
        std::promise<std::string> promise;
        std::future<std::string> done_future = promise.get_future();

        queue.put({{counter, std::move(promise)}});
        //the print_int thread excecutes and prints

        std::string returned_val = std::move(done_future.get()); // wait until its printed
        std::cout << "received " << returned_val << " in main thread\n";
        counter--;
    }
    queue.put({});  // signal thread termination
    thred.join();
    return 0;
}
```

you can find other implementations of a thread-safe multiple consumers queue, or a non-blocking SPSCQueue, this bare-bones implementation is just for illustration.

also if you don't intend on returning a string you should use a smaller type than `std::string`, maybe an `int enum`, and you could wrap the thread and the queue in an RAII object that will signal termination and join the thread in the destructor to have exception safety.